# Can you check what's wrong with my connection? It's a high voltage module connected to battery and pushbutton

Tags: switches, high-voltage

[image]

Please check what's wrong with my connection.  I already tried to push the button, but it didn't produce any lighting spark.

Comment: What is the polarity of the module wires? How do you know they are correct? What voltage the module works with on input? How much current the module takes in? How do you know it works with 9V battery at all?

Comment: And after that check how your button works, its possible that in your current configuration it e.g. connects top left with bottom left as well as top right with bottom right -> you never close the circuit.

Comment: Do you have any schematics over the circuit? Just a picture of wires, a black box etc does not enlighten.

Comment: This most likely will work. Are you sure the wires are close enough together to make a spark? Are you sure the battery wires are connected the right way around?

Comment: If you would share the model number or spec sheet of the module others might be able to help. It is likely that the input power requirement is fairly high, possibly more that a standard 9V battery can provide. You might try using a battery assembly/pack made up from 6 AA or C size alkaline batteries instead.